# Migrating the KDE configuration files

Tags: kde, configuration, migration

I'm a KDE user, and When I switch Linux distributions, I don't want to copy my entire home folder, since most of the configuration files there will be created automatically when I install\run programs on the new installation.

There are, however, some applications that I've put a lot of work into their configuration, and I like to hand-pick their configuration files that I want to migrate to the new installation.

Now, I'm having trouble doing that with the KDE configuration itself - I can't find my way around the `.kde` and `.kde4`. I don't want to migrate the entire folder - but I need some specific settings from there.

So, the question is - what do I need to do to migrate the following KDE settings:

- File associations
- Activities

That's it. I need a way to migrate those - be it copying specific files, copying parts of files, or using a tool.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the file associations are stored in

- ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

For the KDE acitivies have a look at these files

- activitymanagerrc
- plasma-desktop-appletsrc

Comment: OK, the mime types file looks simple enough, and so is `activitymanagerrc`, But `plasma-desktop-appletsrc` seems full of legacy configurations. Is it enough if I copy the `Containment` section that have `activity=` set to the activity I want to migrate, and all the `Containment` sections that have the same index?

Comment: plasma-desktop-appletsrc stores the plasma containments, so applets, wallpaper and stuff like that for your activity. It might be sufficient to copy the section with the activity id. But im not sure if this is the recommend practice. I would copy activitymanagerrc, plasma-desktoprc and plasma-desktop-appletsrc to be safe

Comment: OK, thanks!  Though seeing how messy that file is, I think I prefer to configure that activity myself than to carry legacy configurations.